# How to upload an app to Apple app store with different company and developer names?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

It should be so easy but I couldn't find any methods to **define a different name for the developer field** for an app store app.

For example: Most of the Electronic Arts games have different company and developer names. Command & Conquer Red Alert **game belongs to Electronic Arts** company but it is **developed by EA Swiss Sarl** company.

How can I achieve this?

[image: Example of different company and developer names]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you submit an application, Apple will ask you to choose the company name as it will appear in iTunes.

> Company Name (Artist Name) – the company name that will be displayed on the App Store. For example, “Cyberinteractive” seen above in iTunes Connect, refers directly to the name that will appear in the upper left hand corner of your product page in the App Store. Your company name is a key piece of organizational meta-data for your applications on the App Store because when customers click on this name, they will be led to a page that contains all currently live applications sent through your developer account.

But be aware that it cannot be changed afterwards:

> IMPORTANT: Your primary language and company name cannot be edited once submitted on this page. The settings will apply to all applications added to your account. Be sure these settings are correct before continuing.

Everything is explained in details in the [iTunesConnect Developer Guide (PDF)](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

**EDIT**

The terms are very confusing. I got confused myself. The *Company Name* mentioned in my answer would be "Electronic Arts". I realized you are talking about the **real** company name (EA Swiss SARL), it's the legal name of your company, listed in your "Organization Profile" in Apple Member Center. I checked my account, and it cannot be change. I believe you can contact Apple Dev support at [devprograms@apple.com](http://devprograms@apple.com) and ask them to change your legal name. But they will probably require legal documents to do so.

Comment: But for the example @eren gave, wouldn't the Company Name be Electronic Arts rather than EA Swiss Sarl?

Comment: Thank you but I was asking how to change **developer name** as seen in the screenshot?

Comment: @BenClayton You are right, I got confused by the terms. I edited my original answer.

Comment: @eren I edited my answer, it's the only way I know to change this name.